# Reducing repetition when accessing an array in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

```
for i = 0 to array.length  
    if array(i) = 2 and array (i+1) = 3 and .. and .. .. then
        do xx on array (i+20)
        ..
        ..
    end if
next
```

i need to check an array for a specific combination of numbers before i perform an operation, and i need to know the start point of the array as well. does anybody know how i can remove repetition because it's kind of hard to read when you have so many conditions?

array will be typically something like 02 0101 0000 so i need to check 10 consecutive values before i perform any operation

Comment: for i = 0 to array.length - 1

for k = 0 to 10

if array(i+k) = xx

next

next

this doesn't work because the numbers in the sequence are different.. 02 01 01 00 00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  Dim j As Integer = 0
        Dim b() = {1, 1}
        Dim tempFlg As Boolean = False
        Dim a() As Integer = {0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}
        For i As Integer = 0 To a.Length - 1
            If a(i) = b(0) Then
                For j = 1 To b.Length - 1
                    If a(i + j) = b(j) Then
                        tempFlg = True
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        If tempFlg = True Then
            MsgBox("Item present")
        End If
```

Comment: i think that there is a small problem. if the first case for a(i + j) = b(j) is true then tempflg will be true, while it should check all the way until the for loop is done?